# Rails, sort by associated model count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Deal` model that `has_many :clicks`. I want to sort some deals:

```
@deals = current_user.deals
```

by how many `clicks` they have. How can I do that? `Click` has `deal_id` as a field of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `counter_cache` to the `Deal` model to avoid improve database queries. For more information about `counter_cache` see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache

Than it is just:

```
current_user.deals.order(:clicks_count)

# or when deals are already loaded
current_user.deals.sort_by(:clicks_count)
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be a prime candidate for a scope. You can do something like this in Deals.rb:

```
scope :sorted, -> { sort_by(:clicks_count) }
```

You can then call:

```
Deals.sorted OR current_user.deals.sorted
```

You can even use a default scope if you always want to sort on that field no matter what:

```
default_scope, -> { sort_by(:clicks_count) }
```